# How to create a canvas element inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, html5-canvas

I have an iframe in which there is DIV element "pageContainer1". I want to be able to add a canvas element in that DIV element and access it to draw something on it. I have tried this so far but doesn't seem to work.

```
var can=document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.document.getElementById("pageContainer1");

var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.id="testcanvas";

can.appendChild(canvas);
var can1=document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.document.getElementById("testcanvas");
var ctx= can1.getContext('2d');

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(20,20);
  ctx.lineTo(100,100);
  ctx.stroke();
```

please suggest some way to do it, even if by using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify that the iframe is fully loaded and that you are getting a valid element back in variable "can"
2. is there a reason why you need to get the canvas a second time when you already have access to it in the variable "canvas"?  try removing that and seeing if it works.
3. try inspecting the page and making sure that the canvas has been added

**EDITED**
see if this helps:

```
function loaded() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('thisistheiframe');

    var iframediv = iframe.contentWindow.document;

    iframediv.body.innerHTML += '<canvas id="thecanvas" style="background-color:red; width:100px; height:100px"></canvas>';

    var c = iframediv.getElementById('thecanvas');

    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
    ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mW8kv/

**EDIT 2**
updated fiddle to use createElement instead of just setting html:

```
var can = iframediv.createElement('canvas')
can.id = 'thecanvas';
iframediv.body.appendChild(can);

var c = iframediv.getElementById('thecanvas');
```

Comment: what do you mean by that i already have access to the "canvas". I think you didnt understand my question. I want to add a canvas in a DIV element present in iframe. how to do it? any suggestions.  The above code is showing error."undefined is not a function" for line can.appendChild(canvas)